# Udp multicast send and receive with same socket but different port

Tags: c++, qt, udp, multicast

My purpose is receive udp packet from multicast address , encrypt it and send it to same multicast address but different port.

It work fine but after a while sender is fail and the error show up

> QAbstractSocket::NetworkError      "Unable to send a message"

It continue for a second, data receive is fine but it can't send.

Here it my init socket part

```
udp_socket = new QUdpSocket();
udp_socket->bind(QHostAddress::AnyIPv4, 9000, QUdpSocket::ShareAddress | QUdpSocket::ReuseAddressHint);
udp_socket->joinMulticastGroup(QHostAddress("225.0.0.1"));
QObject::connect(udp_socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(handleMessage()));
QObject::connect(udp_socket, SIGNAL(errorOccurred(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)), this, SLOT(showError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)));
```

And this is my handle packet part

```
qint64 size = udp_socket->pendingDatagramSize();
QByteArray ts_packet;
ts_packet.resize(size);
qint64 received = udp_socket->readDatagram(ts_packet.data(), size);
if (received == -1) {
    return;
}
encryptBuffer(ts_packet, iv);
qint64 sent = udp_socket->writeDatagram(ts_packet, QHostAddress("225.0.0.1"), 5678);
```

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: If there are packets that are send out (should be testet by try to receive the encrypted packets), my guess would be that part of the network stack can not cope with the amount of datagrams you send out.

Comment: I have test receive and decrypt packets. It works fine. And for more information. Input source is video and I send it using ffmpeg.